# Как переустановить nvm после удаления его папки

Tags: linux, node.js, github, ssh, putty

У меня на виртуальном хостинге с cPanel и CloudLinux были установлены nvm и nodejs, но когда с ними начались непонятные проблемы, то я тупо удалил папку /nvm и кажется /npm. Теперь пытаюсь установить nvm заново через

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

но в терминале Putty после

```
remote: Counting objects: 264, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (229/229), done.
```

получаю ошибки

```
error: cannot fork() for --shallow-file: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: fetch-pack: unable to fork off index-pack
Failed to clone nvm repo. Please report this!
```

Как решить проблему и успешно переустановить nvm? И если его нужно сначала корректно и полностью удалить, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Были запущены процессы под нодовским forever. Узнал pid процессов через

```
ps aux | grep node
```

потом поудалял через

```
kill <pid>
```

и потом смог успешно переустановить nvm